# Having troubles creating and formatting Word tables from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm new to MS Word VBA and am having troubles with manipulating Word documents from Excel.

The Biggest problem so far is: codes that work in Word VBA just don't work in Excel. Very strange and frustrating.

Below are the codes:

```
Sub abc()
Dim MSWordApp As Object, MSWordDoc As Object

    Set MSWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set MSWordDoc = MSWordApp.Documents.Add
    MSWordApp.Visible = True
    With MSWordDoc
        With .PageSetup
            .TopMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.51)
            .BottomMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.51)
            .LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.51)
            .RightMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.51)
        End With
        .Tables.Add Range:=.Range(0, 0), NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=2
        With .Tables(1)
            .Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
            .Rows.HeightRule = wdRowHeightExactly
            .Rows.Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(9.55)
            .Columns.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
            .Columns.PreferredWidth = Application.CentimetersToPoints(9.9)
        End With
    End With

    MSWordApp.Activate
    Set MSWordApp = Nothing
    Set MSWordDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

These codes work perfectly in MS Word (Of course I've changed the names of object etc when I use them in MS Word).

However, weird things happen in Excel:

1) ".Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter" just don't work at all. The Rows.Alignment of the Word table just remains as default.

2) ".Columns.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints" causes error in Excel. It works fine in Word; though in Excel, an empty error msg will pop up when every time I call this property. Have no idea why...

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Word VBA library in your excel VBA module?

Comment: @Greg Viers ...God. What you said is exactly the cause. Silly newbie mistake

Comment: I'll submit a proper answer for other newbies that come along. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When controlling Microsoft Word from Excel VBA, you need to add a reference to the Microsoft Word Object Library. To do so, make sure you are on your module in the VBA window, and then click `Tools` then `References...`. In the popup, scroll down to find "Microsoft Word XX.X Object Library". The version # will vary based on what you have installed.

[image: Add reference to Word object library]

If it doesn't show in the list, you can find it on your hard drive, by clicking "Browse..." and navigating to the program files folder where MS Word is installed, then selecting the file called "MSWORD.OLB".

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is written for use with late binding, you should NOT be adding a reference to Word. Instead, you need to either define or replace the Word constants you're using. For example, instead of:

```
.Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
.Rows.HeightRule = wdRowHeightExactly
```

you could use:

```
.Rows.Alignment = 1  '1=wdAlignRowCenter
.Rows.HeightRule = 2 '2=wdRowHeightExactly
```

Alternatively, after:

```
Dim MSWordApp As Object, MSWordDoc As Object
```

you would insert:

```
Const wdAlignRowCenter as Long = 1: Const wdRowHeightExactly as Long = 2
```

Otherwise, if you're going to set a reference to Word, you should make your code consistent with early binding throughout. For example, instead of:

```
Dim MSWordApp As Object, MSWordDoc As Object

    Set MSWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set MSWordDoc = MSWordApp.Documents.Add
```

you might use:

```
Dim MSWordApp As New Word.Application, MSWordDoc As Word.Document

    Set MSWordDoc = MSWordApp.Documents.Add
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise! I realized what you said after I posted the thread, many changes were made and the codes I'm working on are now quite different from the OP :P

Comment: Btw, what's the difference between declaring MSWordDoc As Word.Document then add one more line to add new doc, and declaring MSWordDoc As New Word.Document so no need for another line? For me they work similarly and I'm not sure which is more preferable.

Comment: The code I posted doesn't declare MSWordDoc As New Word.Document - it declares MSWordApp As New Word.Application. The two are quite different.

Comment: Yeah I know that. What I was trying to say is, in the file I'm working on I just declare MSWordDoc As New Word.Document and don't add the "Set...MSWordApp.Documents.Add" line. It works fine though I'm not sure if there's any difference between my codes and your example.

Comment: The codes posted in the OP has already been modified, a lot :P so what I asked in the previous comments is only about the difference between 1) Declaring MSWordDoc As Word.Document then add one more line to add new doc, and; 2) Declaring MSWordDoc As New Word.Document and don't add the "Set...MSWordApp.Documents.Add" line.